# Create factor for multiple dataframes using Loop function

Tags: r, loops

I have mutliple data frames (different size of rows, however, same columns). I want to create a factor in each of them using a loop.

```
list.dfs <- list(d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8)

for (i in 1:length(list.dfs)){
  d[i]$Gender <- factor(d[i]$Gender,
  levels = c(1, 2, 3),
  labels = c("female", "male", "divers")
)
}
```

This is not working

Comment: It should be `list.dfs[[i]]$Gender`.

Comment: Yeah, that is working now, however, the variables are not saved in d1 through d8. Do you maybe have an idea?

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72361728/edit) with the output of `dput(d1)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(d1, 20))`. And say in the question whether all `d1` through `d8` have the same structure.

Answer (score 1):

R would not read d[i] as the object d1 if i = 1. You can access items of a list using [[i]]. Note that `class(list.dfs[1])` is `list` while `class(list.dfs[[1]])` is `data.frame`.

As an example

```
#example data
list.dfs <- list(structure(list(gender = c(1, 2, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)), structure(list(gender = c(1, 2, 3)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L)))

#check first item
list.dfs[[1]]

  gender
1      1
2      2
3      3

#use for loop to access all items of the list, apply function
for(i in 1:length(list.dfs)){
  list.dfs[[i]]$gender <- factor(list.dfs[[i]]$gender, levels = c(1, 2, 3),
                             labels = c("female", "male", "diverse"))

}
```

You also might want to read into `lapply` which applies a function on every object in the list.

```
#example using lapply
lapply(list.dfs, FUN = function(x) x$gender <- factor(x$gender, levels = c(1,2,3), labels = c("female", "male", "diverse")))
```

Regarding your comment (assign objects in the list to global environment).

```
#say we used that lapply function before and end up with this list
list.dfs <- list(structure(1:3, .Label = c("female", "male", "diverse"), class = "factor"), 
    structure(1:3, .Label = c("female", "male", "diverse"), class = "factor"))
```

Then we can add names to the list according to the order the items were put in the list and assign list objects to global environment.

```
#add names (will be the object names later)
names(list.dfs) <- c("d1", "d2")

#assign to global environment
for(i in 1:length(list.dfs)){
  assign(names(list.dfs)[i], list.dfs[[i]])
}
```

Note, I am not a fan of assigning objects like that. Personally I would probably write a function and use that function 8 times. E.g.

```
#create function
gender_fun <- function(x){
  #read data.frame
  dt1 <- x
  
  #set gender
  dt1$gender <- factor(dt1$gender, levels = c(1,2,3), labels = c("female", "male", "diverse"))

  #return
  return(dt1)
}

#apply function on the data.frames
dt1 <- gender_fun(dt1)
dt2 <- gender_fun(dt2)
#etc...
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the advice with lapply. This is working. How can I save the new factor in all of the dataframes? So I want to overwrite the numeric gender in all data frames with the factor gender.

Comment: You can use dt1 <- list.dfs[[1]], dt2 <- list.dfs[[2]] etc.. But going back to the individual data.frame objects would defeat the purpose of making the list?

Comment: Oh so I actually do need the list? So how would the command look like for the lapply function? I just wanted to change Gender in all 8 dataframes to a factor without having to write the same command 8 times. Sorry for the confusion. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Adjusted answer accordingly. You can use ```assign``` but can consider writing a function and use that function for each data.frame individually. Or keep working with the list so you can use ```lapply``` like functions. I personally avoid using assign.

Answer (score 1):

Call your `factor` instruction in a `lapply` loop and assign the result back to `list.dfs`.

```r
list.dfs <- list(structure(list(Gender = c(1, 2, 3)), 
                           class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)), 
                 structure(list(Gender = c(1, 2, 3)), 
                           class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L)))

list.dfs <- lapply(list.dfs, \(x) {
  x$Gender <- factor(x$Gender, levels = c(1, 2, 3), labels = c("female", "male", "divers"))
  x
})

list.dfs
#> [[1]]
#>   Gender
#> 1 female
#> 2   male
#> 3 divers
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>   Gender
#> 1 female
#> 2   male
#> 3 divers
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Maybe I was wrong about using the list in the beginning I read this is in another post. See my script below. Frames from 1 to 7 have the same columns, however, different amount of rows. I was just thinking of using a more efficient to run function over multiple data frames

d1$Sex <- factor(d1$Sex,
  levels = c(1, 2, 3),
  labels = c("female", "male", "inter")
)

d2$Sex <- factor(d2$Sex,
  levels = c(1, 2, 3),
  labels = c("female", "male", "inter")
)

....


d7$Sex <- factor(d7$Sex,
  levels = c(1, 2, 3),
  labels = c("female", "male", "inter")
)

Comment: @Joshua No, you were not wrong in putting the df's in a list, that's where they should be. 1) Don't clutter the globalenv; 2) lists are easy to process; 3) apply the same sequence of instructions to all list members. That's the R way.

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. Appreciate all your help :-)